# Node.js memory filling up

Tags: node.js, memory

I'm trying to write a program that downloads a large zip file, unzips it in memory, and then pushes the contents (a series of CSV files) to MongoDB. However, I keep hitting a point where the program halts and prints

```
FATAL ERROR: CodeRange::GetNextAllocationBlock Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

I've been setting buffers to null when they're no longer in use, setting records to null once they're in Mongo, and preventing more than one file from processing at a time. None of this has helped. Are there any more tricks to releasing memory?

Comment: You accepted my answer. Did some of my tips work?

Comment: Yes, I increased the heap size and spawned separate child processes for each file within the CSV... it worked like a charm. I'm very intrigued by `freelist` though... more research to be done!

Comment: Yup freelist looks interesting. Too bad it is not documented properly. How about ram as filesystem? Have you tried that?

Comment: Not yet, since your other suggestions got the job done. I'll have to experiment with that though because it's a cool idea

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Somethings I would consider would be(not sure if it will all work out as desired):

**Make sure references are gone:**

- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nodejs/ddXqNI_e_pU/NKMHmz4RLsoJ

**Performing GC manually and increase v8 heap size:**

- http://blog.caustik.com/2012/04/11/escape-the-1-4gb-v8-heap-limit-in-node-js/

**Spawning(and killing) child process from parent process to do work:**

- http://www.robsearles.com/2011/09/28/nodejs-experiments-with-processes/

That way I think the OS will reclaim memory for child process even if it is not returning memory.

**Ram as filesystem:**

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-create-linux-ram-disk-filesystem/

That way you can treat filesystem as memory(let operating system put it into memory).

**Use freelist:**

- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nodejs/ddXqNI_e_pU/EP0xUi04xl8J

Answer (score 0):

node.js has a hard 1.4Gb limit for memory allocations. But I dont think that downloading large files to memory is good idea anyway, I suggest writing file to disk, unzip to disk, and then push to MongDB. This way you are always will be operating just small chunks of data in memory